# How to disable smartphone camera's pre-flash and reduce time lag between flash and shooting?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have an old Canon G9 digital compact and external flash, which is triggered by the built-in flash of the Canon G9 via an optical cable (for underwater photography).

I decided to try whether an external flash would trigger from the built-in flash of smartphone (Samsung S10 in my case).

But no success...

1. When the phone's flash fires, it first makes a long pre-flash, and then main flash while taking the foto. The external flash triggers to both pre-flash and main flash. I don't need pre-flash. I set all the parameters manually (shutter speed, aperture, ISO).
2. Between the firing of the phones's flash (which comes after pre-flash) and actual taking foto, there is a certain time lag.
   Something like this:
   Phone pre-flash fires -> phone pre-flash goes off -> phone main flash fires  -> external flash fires from phone flash -> external flash goes off -> phone camera taking foto -> phone main flash goes off.

Thus external flash goes off BEFORE phone's camera taking foto.

Actually the questions - is it possible to somehow turn off pre-flash, and is it possible to make phone's camera start shooting at the same time as the phone flash fires (for example, using Camera2 API)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try manual flash control in camera2 - set [CONTROL_AE_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AE_MODE) to `ON` instead of `ON_AUTO_FLASH` or the other flash-using modes, and then set [FLASH_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#FLASH_MODE) to [SINGLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#FLASH_MODE_SINGLE) for the actual photo capture request.

But note that because most mobile cameras use [rolling shutter sensors](https://www.photometrics.com/learn/advanced-imaging/rolling-vs-global-shutter) and have no physical shutter, the flash duration has to be long enough to cover all sensor rows equally (to ensure uniform brightness for the whole image).  So the flash may have to turn on right at start of the first row and stay on until the end of the last one, if the exposure time is short enough.

A long enough exposure time, one such that there is a point in time at which all rows are actively being exposed, would allow a true strobe flash to be used.

The exposure time has to be at least as long as the frame readout duration for that to be the case: in a rolling shutter sensor, the first row readout starts at time `T_r1 = T`, and the last frame readout starts at time `T_rlast = T + f,` where `f` is the frame duration.  As such, exposure starts at time `T_e1 = T - e` for row 1, and `T_elast = T + f - e` for the last row, where `e` is the exposure duration.  So for all rows to be exposing at once, you need `T_elast < T_r1`, which means `T + f - e < T` or simplified, `e > f`.

So if you have a 1/30s frame duration (often the shortest possible at full resolution), your exposure time has to be more than 1/30s for there to be a time for a strobe flash to fire.  This is similar to what happens with [focal-plane curtain shutters](https://www.slrlounge.com/solving-a-common-off-camera-flash-problem-the-black-band/) on dSLRs at too-short exposure times.

It's possible your external flash will fire too early still, since the phone's flash will turn on at/just before `T_e1` and you don't want to fire your flash before `T_elast`, which is `f` ms later (so at 30fps, 33 ms later).  If your flash unit has any sort of delay adjustment, that may help here.